# Splitting child node from XML file into their own XML files

Tags: java, xml, dom, parsing

I have an XML file (on the left) and I want to create multiple files (on the right):

```
<ParentNode>                                  file1:
    <ChildNode>                               <ParentNode>
        <node></node>                             <ChildNode>
    </childNode>                                      <node></node>
    <ChildNode>                                   </childNode>
        <node></node>                         </ParentNode>
    </childNode>                              file2:
    <ChildNode>                               <ParentNode>
        <node></node>                             <ChildNode>
    </childNode>                                      <node></node>
</ParentNode>                                      </childNode>
                                              </ParentNode>
```

I am trying to take the first child node from the original XML file and add it to a new one but I keep getting errors around replacing nodes.

I want to do something like the following

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document newDocument;

 Node firstChild = document.getFirstChild();
 NodeList childNodes = firstChild.getChildNodes();

 Element parentNode;
 for (int i = 1; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++ ) {
     newDocument = docBuilder.newDocument();
     parentNode = newDocument.createElement("ParentNode");
     newDocument.appendChild(parentNode);
     newDocument.getFirstChild().appendChild(childNodes.item(i));
 }
```

but I get an error

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.
```

any help pointing in the right direction appreciated!

Comment: Where is document coming from ? Is it declared somewhere else?

Comment: The document format is declared in 3rd party application, Im trying to extract data from an excel spreadsheet by saving as xml and then use the third parties import tool which requires the files as individual files and not one great big file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Java documentation,

Use [cloneNode](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#cloneNode(boolean)) method.

> SUMMARY:
>
> ```
> public Node cloneNode(boolean deep)
> ```
>
> Returns a duplicate of this node,
>   i.e., serves as a generic copy
>   constructor for nodes. The duplicate
>   node has no parent; ( parentNode is
>   null.).
>
> Cloning an Element copies all
>   attributes and their values, including
>   those generated by the XML processor
>   to represent defaulted attributes, but
>   this method does not copy any text it
>   contains unless it is a deep clone,
>   since the text is contained in a child
>   Text node. Cloning an Attribute
>   directly, as opposed to be cloned as
>   part of an Element cloning operation,
>   returns a specified attribute (
>   specified is true). Cloning any other
>   type of node simply returns a copy of
>   this node.
>
> Note that cloning an immutable subtree
>   results in a mutable copy, but the
>   children of an EntityReference clone
>   are readonly . In addition, clones of
>   unspecified Attr nodes are specified.
>   And, cloning Document, DocumentType,
>   Entity, and Notation nodes is
>   implementation dependent.

EDIT :

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*; 
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource; 
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Test{
 static public void main(String[] arg) throws Exception{

 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document doc = builder.parse("foo.xml");

 TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
 Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer(); 


 NodeList list = doc.getFirstChild().getChildNodes();

 for (int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++){
    Node element = list.item(i).cloneNode(true);

 if(element.hasChildNodes()){
   Source src = new DOMSource(element); 
   FileOutputStream fs=new FileOutputStream("k" + i + ".xml");
   Result dest = new StreamResult(fs);
   aTransformer.transform(src, dest);
   fs.close();
   }
   }

  }
}
```

Comment: by changing to newDocument.getFirstChild().appendChild(childNodes.item(i).cloneNode(true));

still get same error

Comment: Thanks! Awesome answer, I was just looking to understand what was going wrong and you've gone and done all the work for me!

Answer (score 2):

Nodes in the DOM have a concept of their owning document (hence your `WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR`).

So you need to *import* the node from the original DOM to your new one. See [Document.importNode()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean%29)

Comment: added line newDocument.importNode(childNodes.item(i), true); but still gives same error

Comment: No!, because I'm a complete idiot!
Once I assigned the result I could then append it to the child node and voila theres the XML I need.

i new I just needed nudged in the right direction 

Thanks

Comment: Ah. That's good. A bit of a guess on my part that that was the problem, but glad it worked.