# searching a node matches exactly in a XML using groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

i am performing xml merge of two xml files. xmlSrc will be merged into xmlDest

Code looks like

```
def xmlSrc = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parse(srcFile)
def xmlDest = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parse(destFile)
xmlSrc.children().each{
            if(xmlDest.children().contains(it) == false){
                log "Merging entry ${groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(it)}"
                xmlDest << it
            }else{
                log "not merging: ${groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(it)}"
            }
}
```

Src XML looks like:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<MetadataDirectory xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adfm/metainf" version="11.1.1.0.0">
   <BusinessComponentProjectRegistry path="val1"/>
</MetadataDirectory>
```

Dest looks like

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
    <MetadataDirectory xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adfm/metainf" version="11.1.1.0.0">
       <BusinessComponentProjectRegistry path="val2"/>
    </MetadataDirectory>
```

I am expecting my code to not find a match while merge and insert the node. However, it's always returning true.

Comment: Are you trying to merge both files data in another file? And it is not merging with the code that was shown in the above?

Comment: Please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715779/groovy-copy-xml-elements-from-one-doc-to-another) or [other](http://philip.yurchuk.com/software/merging-xml-files-with-groovy-and-talend/) are helpful.

Comment: no i am merging src file xml into dest file xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to compare the name and attributes of the nodes, you can't just compare nodes.

```
xmlSrc.children().each { srcChild ->
    if(xmlDest.children().find { it.name() == srcChild.name() && it.attributes() == srcChild.attributes() }){
        println "not merging: ${XmlUtil.serialize(srcChild)}"
    }
    else {
        println "Merging entry ${XmlUtil.serialize(srcChild)}"
        xmlDest << srcChild
    }
}
```

And remember, this is a very simplistic solution for this exact use case.  In reality, your `BusinessComponentProjectRegistry` nodes could contain other nodes...  How far do you want to walk the trees to find out if they are the same?  There might be a difference 5 branches down in the xml for example